# Typo3 v. 4.3.3 language files

Tags: content-management-system, translation, typo3, backend

I know that the support for Typo3 v. 4.3.3 has ended, but is there a possibility to get the language files for the backend from somewhere?

The other way would be to update the system, but I want to know if the language packs are somewhere available.

Comment: Even the 4.3.3 is deprecated within that branch (the most recent one would be 4.3.14). It is highly recommended to upgrade the system!

Comment: I think, I saw related issue with 4.5 LTS and some of extensions (DAM, for example).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, Your problem is new TYPO3 localization format, XLIFF.

Probably, You could get updates in XLIFF, and to transform into LLXML format with the help of some external tool ?

For example, I saw a patch for [extdeveval](http://forge.typo3.org/attachments/19066/extdeveval-xliff-2-llxml.diff), which apparently could help.

I didn't saw still any TYPO3 extensions, which proposes "natural" interface between these 2 formats.

Comment: That means that Typo3 v. 4.3.3 uses LLXML format for language files? After your approach I take the current language files and translates them into LLXML format? Wouldn't it be easier to use for example the language files from an existing Typo3 v. 4.3.3? Or does someone provides a download for the missing files?

Comment: Yes, transformation should work fine. I am not sure if 4.5 did switch to XLIFF? If not, you can just copy the files. Actually the LLXML files should be compatible across versions.